# Python Reading Excel cell data trailing Zero

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, type-conversion, win32com

I am using **win32com** client with **python** to manipulate **Excel**. I was able to extract data as expected. But the integer cell comes with decimal like `11001.0` where I'm expecting without decimal.

```
for row in range(1, totalRows+1):
  for col in range(1, totalColumn+1):
        strData = ws.Cells(row, col).value
        print(strData)
```

Result :

```
2123448947.0
8676.0
```

Original Value :

```
2123448947
8676
```

Comment: For all intents and purposes, those numbers are the same as your desired numbers except that they are `float`s not `int`s. Is the issue that you would like to print the numbers and do not wish to have the `.0`s at the end?

Comment: Thanks,  this is my part of test and I need to compare strData by length and trailing Zero is not helping me. I would like to read them as it is in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers you are getting and the numbers you wish to get are pretty much the same when it comes to doing math with them. If you wish to print them and don't want the `.0`s at the ends, you can use `format` like so:

```
print("{:g} {:g}".format(strData[0], strData[1]))
```

*(assuming `strData` types support that)*